# Use Cauchy's Integral Formula to evaluate the following integrals.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Use Cauchy's Integral Formula to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int\limits_\Gamma \frac{1}{{(z-1)^3}{(z-2)^2}}dz$$ where $$\Gamma$$is a circumference of radius $4$ centered at $-2+i$ and traversed once in the positive(with respect to the interior of the disk) direction.

---

My thoughts on the problem:

I HAVE to use the Cauchy Integral Formula. I've been trying to decide the best way to change the expression in the integral.  If I change it to:

$$\int\limits_\Gamma \frac{\frac{1}{{(z-2)^2}}}{{(z-1)^3}}$$

The point 2 is on the boundary of Gamma which means I can NOT use the formula. Are there any other ideas of ways I could change this integral to make it friendly enough to use the formula?

Comment: Are you sure that $z=2$ is on the boundary..? ([See here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2B2%29%5E2%2B%28y-1%29%5E2+%3D+16))

Comment: Just observe the point $z=2$ is outside of $\Gamma$ since $|z-z_0|=\sqrt{(2-(-2))^2+1^2}=\sqrt{17}>4$. Where $z_0=-2+i$

Comment: Okay thank  you! I was looking at a picture that I drew. This is a much better way of verifying if 2 is outside the boundary.

Comment: @Kristin No problem! Drawings can be very unreliable at times. I've definitely fallen into that trap before.

Comment: I have a note that says: If a function f is analytic in a domain D and on the boundary of D then the integral is equal to the value of the function evaluated at z not, multiplied by two pi (i). Am I able to use this in my situation?

Comment: So I did out the work and I was left with $$6\pi{i}$$ Does this seem right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, $2$ is not on the boundary of $\Gamma$. Then your approach is the correct one, letting $f(z)=1/(z-2)^2$, then by the General Cauchy Integral formula:
$$
\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^3} = 2\pi i \frac{f''(z_0)}{2!} =  \frac{6 \pi i}{(z_0-2)^4} = 6\pi i
$$
since $f''(z)=6/(z-2)^4$ and $z_0=1$.